# I am having issues with the react router properties

Tags: reactjs

**Please am trying to access the properties that are made available by the Router component on whatever component that it wraps, like the math, history and location... Yet i cant find them even when added the react developer tool, it still not works. Please someone should help me out am STUCK!**

Comment: Hey, coding can definitely be frustrating at times, but what you posted here in all **bold text** doesn't look like anyone could help you. Please calm down, then include some more context, i.e. your code, errors, and other necessary data so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check your react-router-dom version**

In react-router v6 all these properties are replaced by hooks

- To get a `location` property you should call `useLocation()` hook
- to get a `match` property you should call `useParams()` hook
- to get a `history` property you should call `useNavigate()` hook

and assign them to variables to use them.

Comment: Thank u let me try it out

Comment: Ok and if you have any problem let me know I'll help you.

Comment: Please i have tried those hools out and the error says that it can only be called in react based component

Comment: Yes It should be used in React-based components, if you share the code it would be better